# Covariant versus "ordinary" divergence theorem

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

Let $M$ be an oriented $m$-dimensional manifold with boundary. As stated in Harvey Reall's general relativity notes ([here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hsr1000/lecturenotes_2012.pdf)) or Sean Carroll's book, the "covariant" divergence theorem (i.e. with covariant derivatives) reads:

\begin{equation}
\int_M d^n x \sqrt{\left| g \right|} \nabla_a X^a = \int_{\partial M} d^{n-1} x \sqrt{\left| h \right|} n_a X^a
\end{equation}

where $X^a$ is a vector field on $M$, covariant derivatives are with respect to the Levi-Civita connection, and $h$ denotes the determinant of the metric on $\partial M$ induced by pulling back the metric on $M$.

By contrast, the "ordinary" divergence theorem (i.e. for partial derivatives) can be written as (see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)):

\begin{equation}
\int_V \partial_{\mu_i}X^{\mu_1 \ldots \mu_i \ldots \mu_n} dV = \int_{S= \partial V} n_{\mu_i} X^{\mu_1 \ldots \mu_i \ldots \mu_n}  dS
\end{equation}

where $X^{\mu_1 \ldots \mu_i \ldots \mu_n}$ is now an rank $n$ tensor (all indices written up for simplicity).

When things are stated in this way, it looks like the "ordinary" divergence theorem is valid (in local coordinates) for tensors of all rank, whereas the "covariant" divergence theorem is only valid for vector fields. My question is: is this right? Is there any extension of the "covariant" divergence theorem to higher rank tensor fields, in analogy with the "ordinary" divergence theorem as given above?

Comment: [Generalized Stokes' theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#General_formulation)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment. I'm familiar with the generalised Stokes' theorem, and also with the derivation of the "covariant" divergence theorem from that (it's in the Reall notes..). However, I'm not aware of any generalisation of the "covariant" divergence theorem from vector fields to higher rank tensor fields - whether such a generalisation exists is what I'd really like to know :)

Comment: Um...the "higher rank tensor fields" can be cast as $p$-forms, and then the generalized Stokes holds also for them, unless I am misunderstanding what you are asking.

Comment: Are you looking at $\int_M {d} \omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega $? Because if so, I thought this only held for $\left(m-1\right)$ forms (as it says on Wiki and in the notes). So when you take the Hodge dual $\omega = * X$ and work though, you get the "covariant" divergence theorem above. I wasn't aware generalised Stokes held for all $p$-forms? Thanks for your help in any case though!

Comment: You are free to choose a submanifold of $M$ instead of $M$ of lower dimension, and then this holds for arbitrary $p$-forms - the dimensions of the submanifolds just have to match the dimensions of the $p$-forms.